# What exactly is the following IIF SQL function trying to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
      AND IIF(A.AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId=268, ISNULL(D.IsPursueTermination,0), 1)=1
```

I'm assuming if subtypeid = 268 then set it to NULL and if not set to 0? and also why is there = 1 in the end?

Answer (score 0):

1. `IIF` takes 3 parameters, the first is a condition (`A.AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId=268`), the second is the value to return if the condition is true, and the third is the value to return if the condition is false.
2. The second parameter (`ISNULL(D.IsPursueTermination, 0)`) returns the value in `D.IsPursueTermination` if it is non-null or `0` otherwise.
3. The third parameter (`1`) is there to be true in all cases where the first parameter determined that the value was not `268`
4. Finally the last `=1` results in a true condition whenever the expression on the left evaluates to 1.

So the cases that return true are:

1. `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is 268 and `IsPursueTermination` = 1
2. `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is not 268

The cases that return false are:

1. `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is 268 and `IsPursueTermination` is `NULL`
2. `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is 268 and `IsPursueTermination` = 0

So at a higher level it looks like it's trying to cause the rest of the expression (before the AND at the beginning) to only apply when IsPursueTermination is true (1), but also handle a couple exceptions:

1. If `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is not 268, ignore this piece and allow the whole expression to continue to be true; apparently `IsPursueTermination` only applies when `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is 268.
2. If IsPursueTermination is NULL treat it the same as 0/false.

I believe this expression is functionally equivalent to

```
AND (A.AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId != 268 OR ISNULL(D.IsPursueTermination,0) = 1)
```

Comment: thanks for clear explanation

Comment: And note that, if `D.IsPursueTermination` is a `BIT` (as it appears to be here) the `ISNULL` is redundant since `NULL = 1` isn't true, so `A.AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId != 268 OR D.IsPursueTermination = 1` would do, which is "if `AdminReviewTicketSubTypeId` is `268` then `IsPursueTermination` must be `1`" (implication).